# how to learn react and redux efficiently for an iOS developer?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am an iOS developer and new to front-end tech, but interested in it.Is there any way to learn react and redux quickly and efficiently?

Comment: There's nothing magical about learning React and Redux in relation to learning speed and quality. As with everything, start small, practice and build up. Being na iOS developer you might want to start with React Native (utilize the overlap with iOS development knowledge) and then transition to React.

Comment: Tool/resource recommendation questions are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a free course I built that has nearly perfect reviews for learning React. I think you'll have success with it. If you don't, well, it's free so no loss.

http://courses.reactjsprogram.com/courses/reactjsfundamentals

Comment: Not free anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The best course would be course provided by stephen grider on udemy. Its the best for react and redux